# Proper Way of Handling an Orientation Change in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, orientation

What is the proper way of handling an orientation change in Android? When I researched this question there are two methods that came up.

**1st Method**
Use the methods `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` to store and restore your Activity after being killed by the Android OS after the orientation change.

**2nd Method**
Added `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` to your AndroidManifest.xml so the Activity will not be destroyed when the orientation is changed.

I have tried both methods and they both work, however the first method takes a lot longer to implement. While I do see posts about the 2nd method, I want to know if this is an "accepted" and "proper" way of handling an orientation change. And what are the advantages and disadvantages for each method? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The second method will not allow you to do certain orientation specific stuff such as load a different layout for when the screen is rotated or not (I'm thinking of resource suffixes here). I have not encountered any other ill effects, however the docs state that: "Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last-resort."

More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html where they explain both methods and give the pros and cons and best solution.